# ERROR when accessing TFGM API

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

https://developer.tfgm.com/

I was trying to access data from the TFGM api using the sample javascript code which is using ajax. 
And I try to fix the CORS problem using jsonp. But then it gives me 401 error. Here's my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JSSample</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.tfgm.com/odata/Accidents?$top=10",
      beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "d6bba5f0e3f244bc97b7c5aa4745aae2");
      },
      type: "GET",
      // Request body
      data: "{body}",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    })
      .done(function (data) {
        console.log("success");
      })
      .fail(function () {
        console.log("error");
      });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems like it works with axios in nodejs